# Can Google Play Server be queried to find out if an item was purchased by user?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-developer-api

I'm learning about how I can process in-app purchases from an Android app. I'm reading [**this document**](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html).

Basically, the flow this document describes is as follows:

***My Android app (AKA: the client) communicates with the Google Play App which collects the user's payment information and then communicates with the Google Play Server. The Google Play Server in turn assigns the item to the user and responds to the Google Play App which then tells my client that the purchase succeeded. After that, the client delivers the merchandise, then reports to the Google Play App that the item has been consumed which in turn leads the Google Play Server to mark the item as consumed.***

This raises a security issue: My client delivers the item by telling my server that the item has been purchased. My server is the one that delivers the item. My client app is a multi-player game. Because of this my server is the one that ***has*** to deliver this item. The client app alone cannot do it.

However the above flow requires that my server trust the client. If the client is hacked or is replaced by a malicious program, it could tell my server to deliver any items any number of times. There is now way for my server to verify if these purchases are valid. It's a security risk.

Instead, I would like my server to ask the Google Play Server: Does this user actually own this item? The answer the Google Play Server would report could be trusted. But is there an API to do so? If so, where is that documentation? If there is no such API, then how do multi-player games ensure the security of their purchases??

Answer (score 2):

This [Querying for purchased items](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) topic might help:

**Querying for purchased items**

> To retrieve information about purchases that are made by a user from
>   your app, call the getPurchases method on the In-app Billing service.
>   Pass the In-app Billing API version, the package name of your calling
>   app, and the purchase type (“inapp” or "subs") into the method. Here
>   is an example:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

> The Google Play service returns only the purchases made by the user
>   account that is currently logged in to the device. If the request is
>   successful, the returned Bundle has a response code of 0. The response
>   Bundle also contains a list of the product IDs, a list of the order
>   details for each purchase, and the signatures for each purchase.
>
> To improve performance, the In-app Billing service returns only up to
>   700 products that are owned by the user when getPurchase is first
>   called. If the user owns a large number of products, Google Play
>   includes a String token that is mapped to the key
>   INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN in the response Bundle to indicate that more
>   products can be retrieved. Your application can then make a subsequent
>   getPurchases call and pass in this token as an argument. Google Play
>   continues to return a continuation token in the response Bundle until
>   all of the products that are owned by the user are sent to your app.
>
> For more information about the data that is returned by getPurchases,
>   see In-app Billing Reference. The following example shows how you can
>   retrieve this data from the response:

```
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
   String continuationToken =
      ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

   for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
      String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
      String signature = signatureList.get(i);
      String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

      // do something with this purchase information
      // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
   }

   // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
   // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
}
```

Comment: This seems like it has to be called from the app on the device -- not my server. `"The Google Play service returns only the purchases made by the user account that is currently logged in to the device."` I need to know how my server can find out from Google Play (without trusting the app) what items are purchased but not yet consumed.

Comment: I haven't experimented much with Google Play in app billing like you're doing so all I could cite is the official docs. not sure if what you're doing is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should not trust the purchase made on the client since we've seen third party apps that can be used on a jailbroken android phone that mimic the interaction with the Google Play Store.

You should do the following

1. List item
2. Go through the purchase flow on the app using a purchase token generated on the server.
3. Receive the purchase information on the client
4. Send the purchase information to the server - ensure the purchase token, product, order information is valid
5. Have the server talk to Google to verify the purchase - see https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html
6. Once verified, return the response to the client
7. Have the client return the response to Google - which then marks the purchase as consumed.